# survival curve for a time-dependent predictor

Tags: survival

I am doing survival analysis with a time-dependent predictor. I used an extended cox with heaviside function and got the hazard ratios. But now I am stuck on how to make the survival curve and to get the median survival. (I use SAS, by the way) 
Any advice is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a SAS user, but I assume that you can get a baseline survival function (for an individual with 0 value for all covariates), call it $S_0(t)$. Say your predictor is $x(t)$ and you estimate for it a hazard ratio (versus baseline) as $\beta$.

Then say that a baseline individual has hazard $h_0(t)$ (however you estimate it). The baseline survival is then by definition $S_0(t) = \exp (-\int_0^t h_0(s)ds)$.

The hazard for an individual with predictor $x(t)$ is then $h_0(t) \exp(\beta x(t))$. Then the survival for an individual with predictor $x(t)$ is

$$S(t | x(\cdot)) = \exp\left(-\int_0^t \exp (\beta x(s)) h_0(s) ds\right) $$.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a simple relation between baseline survival and survival with a time-dependent predictor as in the case of time-constant covariates. But it shouldn't be too complicated to calculate that, given that you have an estimate for $h_0$ and an estimate for $\beta$.